# How to find the coordinates of points on the boundary of the polygon using MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, polygon

I am generating a Voronoi cell or a polygon as shown in the figure.[image: Polygon]
I know the coordinates of the vertices of the polygon. Using triangulation, I have created two random points inside the polygon. The blue circles are known. Red is unknown.

My goal is to section the polygon as shown (red dotted lines). To do that, I am finding the coordinates of pt A, B, C and D. I need just four random points on the four different sides of the polygon. Once each boundary red points are connected to the points inside the polygon, the polygon can be divided into 4 random sized sections.

That's the idea. I am finding it hard to find the coordinates of A, B, C, D. I am using the following code:

```
%xnew and ynew are arrays of column vector containing polygon coordinates.
%xline and yline are supposed to be the coordinates of A, B, C, D.

    for k=1:(length(xnew)-1) 
    xline = (xnew(k+1) - xnew(k)) * rand(1) + xnew(k) ;
    yline = (ynew(k) - ynew(k+1))/(xnew(k) - xnew(k+1)) * (xline - xnew(k)) + ynew(k) ;
    end
```